# The window.Print() function is not working in Microsoft Edge (Version 91.0.864.59) when canceled the first time Angular 12 app

Tags: javascript, angular, printing, microsoft-edge

You can reproduce the issue here (using the latest Edge browser version 91.0.864.59):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zbvzap?file=src/app/app.component.html

1. Click on the print button.
2. Close the print dialog.
3. Click on the print button again (the print dialog doesn't open most of the time, sometimes it strangely works). Try in a new tab if not reproducible first try.

Does anyone have a workaround for this?

**Update:**

It can also be reproduced with a plain HTML page (hosted):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-madbq2?file=index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a simple test, I found that it does have such a problem in the version you mentioned of MS Edge.

But after testing in Edge Canary, the problem no longer exists. This shows that the problem has been resolved in a future version, so I don’t think you need to worry about this.